# How to substitute a variable with a default when it's not empty/undefined?

Tags: ansible

For the ansible variable `param` I'd like the behaviour that is similar to the following bash code:

```bash
echo ${param:+--arg=}$param
```

It outputs nothing when the variable is undefined or empty. When the variable has a non-empty value it prints `--arg=value`.

Is this the best that can be done?

```
- debug:
  msg: "{{ (param | default('') | length > 0) | ternary('--arg=', '') + (param | default('')) }}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jinja seems to be simpler

```yaml
  options: |
    {% if param|d('')|length > 0 %}
    --arg={{ param }}
    {% else %}
    {{ '' }}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: TIL you can use jinja2 directly with playbooks

Comment: See [Flow Scalar Styles](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#73-flow-scalar-styles). It's very useful to understand the differences among the styles: *double-quoted, single-quoted and plain (unquoted)*.

Comment: Thanks for the `d()` filter. The if/else doesn't make it shorter, but it's clearer.